# Could not build module - Dead Lock Configuration

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

My App was working fine until last week.
Some errors started to happen, and I don't know why:

[image: First problem ocurring]
After some researches, I've found some "solution":
[image]

Changing "Enable modules (C and Objective-C)" from YES to NO, the problem changes, to another. Some imported libraries can't be imported:

[image]

The App worked fine for years, and I don't know why the error stated.
It's like an Dead Lock situation.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

1- Change enable modules to "NO";
2- Change all "@imports" to "#import", like this:

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
#import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
#import <FirebaseInstanceID/FirebaseInstanceID.h>
#import <FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

//@import Fabric;
//@import Crashlytics;
//@import FirebaseCore;
//@import FirebaseInstanceID;
//@import FirebaseMessaging;
//@import UserNotifications;
```